custom PCB design for UART-TTL to STM32
I have a project where I am using an stm32f103c8t6 to send a 10Hz pulse (as a hard trigger for a camera) and sends data through UART to a connected computer. I'm using this opportunity to learn PCB design, so I'm trying to design a board that uses a Silicon Labs CP2102-GMR chip for the UART-USB conversion. The reason I chose this chip is because I found a schematic for an existing UART to USB board:


I noticed that a lot of pins arent used, and this was my attempt of simplifying the design to only what I need:

I fixed the input voltage to be 5V, so i could remove Header 3, Header 4 is not used so I removed that, and the capacitors and resistors seem to be only there for the LEDs(?). I looked up the model of the surge protector (D1), although I'm not 100% confident I connected the poins correctly.
Questions:

Did I make mistakes in my schematic? I dont think I need the suspend or reset pins, so the design seems to simplify a lot.
If I were to add back the LEDs, could I pretty much use any LEDs, what are the resistors purpose?
what are the capacitors for, just stabilizing the current of the circuit?


A question that may be worth asking is, why are you designing an USB-UART chip for a MCU which has built-in USB functionality. Why not use the native USB of the MCU? Also, that is not a bare MCU but some module with MCU.

Short between ground and 5 V on second page. Missing decoupling capacitors on the same.

@winny What second page you mean, and where the short is?

If you intend to design your own board, you should read Getting Started with STM32F10xxx hardware development first.

U6, left side, pin 7 ang 8.

Yes there are many errors.
First error is that the chip does not even have USB data wires connected to the connector, and there is not even a single bypass capacitor for the supplies.
Just look at the CP2102 data sheet, do not guess why something is there from some other design.
The data sheet will tell you what resistors and capacitors are needed and why, so you can make a minimal design.
Even if the reset resistor is optional it is highly recommended. This information is in the data sheet.
The suspend resistor may or may not beimportant for you, it depends if you want to know about the suspend state or not, which may mean the TXD output to MCU should be ignored by the MCU. Again, data sheet has this information.
And the resistors for LEDs are mandatory current limiting resistors, just like you cannot put a LED directly to a battery as it would burn due to overcurrent, you cannot directly put a LED to an output of digital IO pin of an IC. Always put resistora for LEDs.
The capacitors are supply bypass capacitors for stabilizing the voltage. They are not for LEDs. Also needed by the internal linear regulator to stay stable. Mandatory. The data sheet will tell which capacitor values and types shall be used for best results. Not just any capacitor will do.

If you want to interface TTL-level UART signals to the STM32, you can connect them directly to the STM32's UART RX and TX pins.
If you have RS-232 level signals you will need an RS-232<->TTL interface, like a MAX232, between the RS-232 signals and the STM RX and TX pins.

This is true, but how does it relate to the question asked?

The question title asks about interfacing UART-TTL to STM32 - no mention of USB - so I think I've answered the OP's question, despite him showing a USB<->UART IC.

The OP knows how to connect to STM32. The question is about doing a design for USB to TTL UART (for the STM32) with CP2102.
